# Need exaplanation of 2D arrays ( + passing to a function )

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have 3 questions.

- Could anyone please explain how creating 2D array using pointer to pointer works in C? I know how to "use" it but i do it from some part mechanically without deeper understanding.
- There are like 3 methods creating 2D arrays in C is any of them
  prefered ? if yes then why ?
- What's the best way to pass array to function to be able to work with the same array outside of the function.

Comment: Describe the problem you are having, what your understanding of the problem is and where you are confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always preferred passing a 2D array to any function using double pointer.
For example if there is a function that I create say `int** allocate(int** memptr, int row, int col)` then I would implement the function like below

```
int** allocate(int** memptr, int row, int col){
 int i; 
 memptr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * row); // for how many 1D array you need
 for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
   memptr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * col); // allocating memory for each 1D array
 return memptr;
}
```

and I would call the function like that

```
int** memptr = NULL;
int row, col;
scanf("%d%d", &row, &col);
memptr = allocate(memptr, row, col);
```

There are few other ways to do it but the reason I liked this most is because it is so discrete and the code itself spells out the actual work or process to allocate memory using **pointer to pointers**. Once you allocate how many pointers you want to store and allocate memory for that by `memptr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);` you iterate over a loop and allocate memory for each pointer again by  `memptr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * col);`

This is the best way that I have seen and used personally.